# Same comment for multiple variables

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I'm having the same problem as this person:

[doxygen comment multiple variables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777982/doxygen-comment-multiple-variables-at-once)

I've already tried the suggested solutions in the thread and like the OP, I wasn't able to make doxygen have the same comment for multiple variables. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Grouping of multiple variables is discussed in detail in the doxygen manual section on [grouping](http://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/grouping.html). From the manual you would use something like:

```
//@{
/** Same documentation for both members. Details */
void func1InGroup1();
void func2InGroup1();
//@}
```

If you are having trouble using this you should post some code and show us what you have tried and what output you are gettting. Otherwise your question is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to set the option "DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC" in the "Expert" tab. Them all the members of the group will receive the same comment.